# Error crystal report runtime en windows server 2016

Tags: iis, windows10, crystal-reports, windows-server

He desarrollado una aplicación en asp.net probada en iis de Windows 10 y funciona correctamente.

Ahora el inconveniente que presento es al subirlo en iis de windows server 2016 esta no funciona, aparece este tipo de mensajes al ingresar los parámetros requeridos por el reporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto en windows 10 (En español) como en windows server 2016 (En inglés) tengo las siguientes configuraciones:

Crystal Runtime de 32 bits Version 13.0.25
Sitio web corriendo en pool de aplicaciones con habilitación de aplicaciones de 32 bits

Puede tener algo que ver el idioma de los sistemas operativos?

Comment: Aparentemente el error es por la configuracion regional, el tratamiento de fechas es diferente dependiendo de la configuracion regional

Comment: he colocado los mismos formatos de fecha y hora y el problema persiste

Comment: que hace la formula del reporte que infoma el mensaje de error? podrias poiner el codigo aqui